# Can I call a JavaScript function on an iFrame or similar widget from Python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, d3.js, multilingual, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to mix Python code with D3 vizualizations. Right now I have a bunch of D3 vizualizations and JavaScript functions. I have a couple different ways of embedding the D3, but what I want is to call a function that affects the vizualization AFTER I create it.

For example:

```
createD3Stuff()
for i in [0,1,2,3]:
    executeFunction(i)
```

Where createD3Stuff() generates the vizualization, and executeFunction does something on that vizualization, like creates an element with id=i.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Background information: I am using Jupyter Notebooks, but if there is some other way to get this to work I can switch. I know how to do all the d3 and javascript stuff, it is just getting the python and javascript to interact that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Where do you plan to interact JavaScript with Python? As far as I know you can only run JavaScript on browser or inside node.js with virtual DOM. Both of them do not allow you run Python. And I don't think you can run JavaScript inside Python scripts.

Comment: @paradite I am currently running it in a Jupyter Notebook, which runs in a browser and explicitly allows limited running of Javascript in a python series of scripts. However, there is some separation of the JS and Python, and I can't find a way to pass in arguments or call functions

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

Just try this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("<script>alert('hello world')</script>")
```